# Reduce 3D tensor to 1D tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication

Let's assume, I have a 3 dimensional tensor of shape [a, b, c].
I want to extract one dimension at model run time, e.g. [4, 2, c], so I would end up with with a 1 dimensional tensor [c].

The parameters of a and b are stored in different tensors of shape [a, 1] and [b, 1], so using tf.slice is not an option, as tf.slice only accepts a 1 dimensional scalar tensor.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by parameters of `a` and `b` stored in different tensors?. What are those parameters used for?. Can you give a python/numpy example?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably you need to split the tensor with `tf.split`.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tf.reshape` function, although you need to pass the number of entries in the new tensor as an argument. For instance:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Define a 3D tensor
tensor3d = tf.constant([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]])

# Convert the 3D tensor to 1D
tensor1d = tf.reshape(tensor3d, [12])
```